# How to get data from popup view controller to custom table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, swift4.2

[image]

I have 3 view controllers. First is `MainViewController`.

In this `MainViewController` has custom table view cell as `FoodCell` class with two property as `name` and `price`.

I instantiate this objects in `MainViewController` and when tap to table view cell this objects pass to popup `DetailViewController` which is not table view it is only `View` with labels(foodName and foodPrice labels) and `AddToBasket` button.

And finally I want to pass this class objects from popup `DetailViewController` to `MyCartViewController`. `MyCartViewController` is my final scene for show the `foodNames` and `foodPrices` objects.

(e.g. `MainViewController` is my food menu list. `DetailViewController` is my selected foods list.`MyCartViewController` is my market bag. )

**MainViewController(Food Menu List)**

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,
UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,   UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView!

var imageNames = [ImageNames]()
var searchFoods: [String]!
var priceFood: [Double]!
var searching = false


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    let foodCell = Food(name: ["Hamburger big mac",
                               "Patates",
                               "Whopper",
                               "Steakhouse"], price: [15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0])

    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchFoods = foodCell.name
    priceFood = foodCell.price

    imageNames = [
        ImageNames(name: "images"),
        ImageNames(name: "unnamed"),
        ImageNames(name: "unnamed")
    ]

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return section == 0 ? 1 : searchFoods.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return indexPath.section == 0 ? 130 : 65
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return indexPath.section == 0 ? 100 : 65
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainFoodTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainFoodTableViewCell

        cell.mainFoodCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell.mainFoodCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.mainFoodCollectionView.reloadData()
        cell.mainFoodCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell

    } else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellForFood", for: indexPath) as! MainFoodTitleTableViewCell

        cell.titleLabel?.text = searchFoods[indexPath.row]
        cell.priceLabel?.text = priceFood[indexPath.row].description

        return cell
    }

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "cellForFoodSegue" {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController
        {
            let indexPath = self.mainTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            var foodNameArray: [String]
            var foodPriceArray: [Double]

            foodNameArray = [searchFoods[indexPath.row]]
            foodPriceArray = [priceFood[indexPath.row]]

            destinationViewController.detailFoodName = foodNameArray
            destinationViewController.detailFoodPrice = foodPriceArray

        }

    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  imageNames.count
}

//MARK:- collection view cell size
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 130)
}

//MARK:- //collection view cell data
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainFoodCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainFoodCollectionViewCell
    let img = imageNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.mainFoodImage.image = UIImage(named: img.name)
    return cell
}
}
```

**DetailViewController(Selected Foods List)**

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var foodTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodSubTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPiece: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var drinkPicker: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var menuPieceStepper: UIStepper!

var drinkPickerView = UIPickerView()

var selectDrinkType: [String] = []
var detailFoodName : [String] = []
var detailFoodPrice : [Double] = [0.0]



let foods = Food(name: ["Hamburger big mac",
                           "Patates",
                           "Whopper",
                           "Steakhouse"], price: [15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0])


@IBAction func foodPieceStepper(_ sender: Any) {
}

@objc func foodPieceChangeStepper() {
    let res = menuPieceStepper.value + foods.price.first!
    foodPrice.text = "\(res)"
}

//TODO:- Add to basket
    @IBAction func addBasket(_ sender: Any) {

        let destinationVC = MyCartViewController()

        destinationVC.fromDetailFoodNames = foods.name
        destinationVC.fromDetailFoodPrices = foods.price
   }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if(segue.identifier == "addToCartSegue") {
        if let addToCartVC = segue.destination as? MyCartViewController  {   
            addToCartVC.fromDetailFoodNames = [foodTitle.text]
            addToCartVC.fromDetailFoodPrices = foods.price
    }
   }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menuPieceStepper.value = 0.0
    menuPieceStepper.minimumValue = 0.0
    menuPieceStepper.maximumValue = 30.0
    menuPieceStepper.stepValue = foods.price.first!
    menuPieceStepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(foodPieceChangeStepper), for: .valueChanged)

    drinkPickerView.delegate = self
    drinkPicker.inputView = drinkPickerView
    selectDrinkType = ["Ayran", "Kola", "Su", "Fanta", "Şalgam", "Sprite"]

    foodTitle.text = detailFoodName.description
    foodPrice.text = detailFoodPrice.description


    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Sipariş Detayı"
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:     #selector(self.dismissKeyboard (_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
@objc func dismissKeyboard (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   drinkPicker.resignFirstResponder()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
}

extension DetailViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate,    UIPickerViewDataSource {
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return selectDrinkType.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return selectDrinkType[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let selectedDrink = selectDrinkType[row]
    drinkPicker.text = selectedDrink
}

}
```

**MyCartViewController(My Grocery Bag)**

```
import UIKit

class MyCartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate {

var fromDetailFoodNames: [String?] = []
var fromDetailFoodPrices: [Double?] = []

@IBOutlet weak var myCartTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var totalPriceLabel: UILabel!


let foodNames = [
    "Hamburger big mac",
    "Cemal",
    "Emre",
    "Memo"
]

//TODO-: Delete my cart
@IBAction func deleteMyCart(_ sender: Any) {
}

//TODO: - Approve my  cart
@IBAction func approveCart(_ sender: Any) {
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return section == 0 ? 1 : foodNames.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCartCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCartTableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.last! <= fromDetailFoodPrices.indices.last! {

    let name = fromDetailFoodNames[indexPath.row]?.description ?? ""
    let price = fromDetailFoodPrices[indexPath.row]
    cell.myCartFoodNameLabel?.text = name
    cell.myCartFoodPriceLabel?.text = "\(String(describing: price))₺"

}
    return cell    
}
}
```

Comment: ok i saw your flow , i have a query please tell me, is there any api on detail ViewController for send data? if not create Dictonary [String:Any] add your all data in dictonary [keys : value ], save your dictonary on sepete ekle button in user default, when you are on cart View controller fetch your dictonary  and append in Array [[String:Any]] on viewdidload....

Comment: @sukhwinder-singh No , I am just using dummy datas to be sure about can I pass data with 3 views. If I create Dictionary on Detail VC it will be independent data created on DetailVC? So, it is not about which data is coming from MainVC.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create Custom delegate for him

// eg:- On PopUp View Controller 
// Create protocol
protocol PopUpVCDelegate: class {

    func refresh(text: String) 
}
// declare delegate var
  weak var delegate:PopUpVCDelegate?

// puting value on it 
   self.delegate?.refresh(text: self.mDateTxtFld.text!)

// On Main ViewController (Recieving Data Class)  
extension MainViewController: PopUpVCDelegate {
    func refresh(text: String) {
        self.dateLbl.text = text

    }
}
// and don't forget to call or connect delegate when you present or push popup Vc
//like 

let resultController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpVCID") as? PopUpVC       

        resultController?.delegate = self
  self.present(resultController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

// Hope Its work for you!
```

Comment: I tried 2 times with protocols and delegates but I did not get any result. Could you please use your example with my exact class? I am working with MainViewController which is my first datas in there. Second is DetailViewController from MainViewController. Third and most important view is MyCartViewController.

Comment: But you Have 3 ViewController. i don't know your viewController flow, please describe me if its possible?

Comment: I added image to my question