# Where to set delegate in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I've set up a simple Swift project to try and wrap my head around delegates & protocols. The goal is to pass data between two classes (`SendingClass` & `ReceivingClass`). Two buttons in the `SendingClass` are linked to the delegate which should trigger the Protocol conforming function in the ReceivingClass to execute. This doesn't work unfortunately, I suspect it has to do with where and how I am declaring the `ReceivingClass` as the delegate.

Appreciate your insights, i'm just starting out!

I've tried setting the delegate in various locations (presently within `viewDidLoad`, but cant get it to work).

```
let vc = SendingClass()
vc.statusDelegate = self
```

**SendingClass.swift**

```
import UIKit


protocol StatusDelegate {
    func statusChanged(state: Bool, sender: String)
}

class SendingClass: UIViewController {

    var statusDelegate : StatusDelegate?


    @IBAction func button1Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
      statusDelegate?.statusChanged(state: true, sender: "Button 1")
    }

    @IBAction func button2Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        statusDelegate?.statusChanged(state: false, sender: "Button 2")
    }

}
```

**ReceivingClass.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ReceivingClass: UIViewController, StatusDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let vc = SendingClass()
        vc.statusDelegate = self
    }

    func statusChanged(state: Bool, sender: String) {
        print("Sender = \(sender) , State = \(state)")
    }
}
```

**Expected:** the `ReceivingClass` protocol conforming function (`func statusChanged`) should execute each time the buttons are pressed within the SendingClass.

**Actual:** Nothing happens

Comment: How do you present your `SendingClass`? From the IBActions, I guess you do it from a storyboard.

Comment: Where do you present `SendingClass`?

Comment: @ Dávid Pásztor, @Rico Crescenzio Yes the buttons are presented through a simple story board. I've tested the IBactions with print statements and they seem to work fine.

Comment: @GCr has my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

```
I am using this..
// create extension in your receiving class
extension ReceivingClass: PopUpVCDelegate {
   func statusChanged(state: Bool, sender: String) {
        print("Sender = \(sender) , State = \(state)")
    }
}

// on sending class, when you present your receiving class on any button click
eg.
let resultController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpVCID") as? PopUpVC       

        resultController?.delegate = self
  self.present(resultController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

 //or if not have button add on viewdidload in receiving class

// here is full eg
```

[How to get data from popup view controller to custom table view cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052243/how-to-get-data-from-popup-view-controller-to-custom-table-view-cell/55116806#55116806)

Answer (score 0):

For protocol and delegate, you use it when u want to bring a value from 2nd VC (presented by 1st or pushed by 1st VC) to 1st VC, which is the original. 
From your code, I dont see you presenting or pushing your 2nd VC. that's why it's not working. Hopefully I answered your doubt.

However if you still want to bring a value over from 1st VC to 2nd VC. In second VC, create a variable to receive it

```
var ReceivedData = String()
```

then from your first VC, when u are going to push it,

```
let vc = SendingClass()
vc.ReceivedData = "Whatever you want it to receive"
```

Comment: OK, so the protocol / delegate pattern is reserved for managing the presentation of views on the stack?

Would it be appropriate to use this pattern if the ReceivingClass is in fact the model, and not a ViewController. 

So the ReceivingClass is just listening for changes in the SendingClass and then responding (but not being presented).

Comment: erm..didnt really get your question...And pls do upvote any answers around that helped..New members like me especially..haha

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboard segues, maybe the view controller is instantiated from there so probably you have to use the `prepareForSegue` and get the destination view controller (which is already instantiated for you) in the `ReceivingClass` view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    if let destination = segue.destination as? SendingClass {
        destination.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Also be careful with delegate patter: the delegate property should be declared as a `weak` property to avoid retain-cycle

```
weak var delegate: MyDelegate?
```